# EF Code First Many-to-Many not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Using the Entity Framework Code First paradigm I have defined the following objects and relationships as part of an ASP.Net MVC3 application.  The problem is the many-to-many relationship between the Photo and Gallery objects is not working properly.

Currently a gallery can contain many photos - this is correct.  But a photo can only be associated with one Gallery - this is incorrect. I want a photo to be able to be in many galleries.  If I add a photo to a gallery when it is already associated with another gallery, it is removed from the other gallery.

I would very much appreciate your solutions on how to make this many-to-many relationship work.

Here's my code:

```
public class Photo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Gallery> Galleries { get; set; }
}

public class Gallery
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Photo> Photos { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    /* I would expect the following to cause a lookup table to 
     *  be created but it isnt */
    modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>().HasMany<Gallery>(p => p.Galleries);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Gallery>().HasMany<Photo>(g => g.Photos);
}
```

I am using the following code within my own custom database initializer.

```
public void InitializeDatabase(PhotoDBContext context)
{
    var dbCreationScript = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
    Log(dbCreationScript);
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(dbCreationScript);
}
```

By logging the dbCreationScript variable I can see that the relevant sql that is generated for these tables is as follows.

```
create table [dbo].[Galleries] (
    [ID] [int] not null identity,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Photo_ID] [int] null,
    primary key ([ID])
);

create table [dbo].[Photos] (
    [ID] [int] not null identity,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) null,
    [Gallery_ID] [int] null,
    primary key ([ID])
);

alter table [dbo].[Photos] add constraint [Gallery_Photos] foreign key ([Gallery_ID]) references [dbo].[Galleries]([ID]);
alter table [dbo].[Galleries] add constraint [Photo_Galleries] foreign key ([Photo_ID]) references [dbo].[Photos]([ID]);
```

As you can see there is no SQL generated to create a lookup table which is probably why the relationship is not working - why isnt a lookup table being created?

Comment: The ID member should be named Class + ID e.g. PhotoId and GalleryId.  This may help.  As you can see in the db scripts it has added a pk for the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to use something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Entity<Photo>()
            .HasMany<Gallery>(x => x.Galleries)
            .WithMany(x => x.Photos)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.MapLeftKey("ID");
                x.MapRightKey("ID");
                x.ToTable("GalleryPhotos");
            });
}
```

Comment: Using "ID" as the field name for both MapLeftKey and MapRightKey caused problems so I changed it to `x.MapLeftKey("PhotoID");                 x.MapRightKey("GalleryID");`.  Otherwise a perfect solution. Thank very much @Ken Pespisa.

Comment: There is a condition where even this will not fix the problem. I had two many to many relationships on the same tables, one for a list of default items, and one for a list of instance items.

 I had to create another collection of Items(Photos in this example, ex[ICollection<> DefaultPhotos]). Then in my second many-to-many mapping I used "WithMany(x => x.DefaultPhotos). Then my error went away.