# How do I get the EntityFramework to check for 2 parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 related objects (non relevant properties omitted for brevity):

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductPrice Price { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public int     ID         { get; set; }
    public int     ProductID  { get; set; }
    public int     VerticalID { get; set; }
    public decimal Value      { get; set; }

    public virtual Product  Product  { get; set; }
    public virtual Vertical Vertical { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString("C");
    }
}

public class Vertical
{
    public int ID      { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Product price varies based on the current "vertical". The current vertical will probably (eventually) be stored in a session, but for the time being, let's assume that this will be a query string parameter. (e.g. `mydomain.com?VerticalID=2`).

**My question**

When a user visits `mydomain.com/products?VerticalID=2` or `mydomain.com/products/?VerticalID=2` how can I get the Entity Framework to select/assign the correct price based on the ProductID **and** the VerticalID - making this possible?:

```
@Model.Price.ToString()
```

---

## Update 1 (sample data and DB structure)

Here are my tables with dummy content:

**Products**

[image: Products table]

**ProductPrices**

[image: ProductPrices table]

**Verticals**

[image: Verticals table]

#### Relationship Explanation

There should be one price, per product, per vertical. The query would look something like:

```
-- Let's assume ProductID = 2 and VerticalID = 1 (e.g. mydomain.com/products/2?VerticalID=1)
SELECT * FROM ProductPrices WHERE ProductID = 2 AND VerticalID = 1
```

The above query would return 1 row (which is what it should always return)

---

## Update 2 (another example)

For illustrative purposes I added the `VerticalID` property to Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID              { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model        { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber   { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID      { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int VerticalID = 1;

    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductPrice Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDocument> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when actually trying to execute this, I am getting the following error:

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Print_Solutions.Models.ProductPrice' and 'Print_Solutions.Models.Product'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.
```

**How can I tell entity to use both VerticalID and Product.ID when retrieving the price?** (using the test data I have, if this was product 1, this product should map to ID  1 of the product price table, and cost $100).

Comment: It is difficult to understand your DB structure. What is the relation between Product and ProductPrice. At first glance this should be one to many, but you have ProductPrice Price property in your Product class, as it is one to one. How can you choose between Prices of different Verticals if you have only one price per product? Also: please add code how do you currently get list of products without additional condition for price.

Comment: @IhorDeyneka I just added an update that should answer your questions. It is a one-to-many. There should only ever be one price per product, per vertical.

Comment: What's the problem? Select the `PropductPrice` filtering by `ProductId` and `VerticalId`!!

Comment: @JotaBe My problem is that I am unsure how to get the EntityFramework to do this. Forming a query would be very easy, but I am not sure how to tell Entity to take VerticalID into account.

Comment: Excuse me for telling that that's the very, very basics of EF and LINQ. You should make a tutorial urgently. However, I've post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your `DbContext` has a collection of `ProductPrice` named `ProductPrices`, using LINQ you simply has to make this query:

```
var price = ctx.ProductPrices.Where(pp =>
   pp.ProductId = productId && pp.VerticalId == verticalId).SingleOrDefault();
```

Where `productId` and `verticalId` are the available paramters that come from the action paramters, the session, or wherever they are.

The use of single or default warranties that there's only one value on the database, or that there is none, and, on that case, you get `null` as a result of the query.

As for your updates I see that your problem is also related to the definition of the relations in the model.

There are 3 ways to achieve it:

- using EF conventions. To achive this, change the name of the ID properties of your entites: for example use `ProductId`, instead of `ID` and the conventions will build the model for you
- using attributes. In this particular case use [ForeignKeyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.foreignkeyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) where it applies
- [using the fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591620)

You have [some more info on relationships here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx), with a few simple samples.

Comment: Do you recommend that I stick this in the `Product` constructor? I was hoping for a way to make Entity map this on its own, but I think I would be okay with this solution.

Comment: I don't understand what kind of crazy design you're using... Are you using DI and you're trying to inject an entity instead of a service? You should not treat an entity as a dependency!!

Comment: I think I am doing a poor job of explaining my intent. a product's price depends on the current vertical. So for product 2, the price is either $150, or $149.99, depending on whether the vertical ID is 1 or 2. I am trying to automap that assignment. The relationship is still a one-to-many, however.

Comment: Nope, your explanation is pretty clear and my solution works. I don't know where is the problem. I don't understand what you mean by "tell entity to use both VerticalID and Product.ID when retrieving the price". How are you getting your entity from the DB?

Comment: Oops! I finally see that your problem is defining the model.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show you how to create your code first model to define the one to many relationships (you need to define two relationships, one for Vertical, the other for Product). However, my sample query do also work,without the need to define these relationships, because it's directly using the Ids.

Answer (score -1):

I was never able to figure out how to fix the models or use the fluent API. I did some lazy loading instead. If anyone has a better solution, please post it.

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID              { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model        { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber   { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID      { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }

    public int VerticalID = 1;
    private ProductPrice _price;

    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDocument> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }


    // Lazy Loading
    public ProductPrice Price
    {
        get
        {
            if (_price == null)
            {
                var db = new ApplicationContext();
                _price = db.Prices.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == ID && p.VerticalID == VerticalID);
            }

            return _price;
        }
    }
}
```