# How can I link these models with the Entity Framework (possibly using the fluent api?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is an attempt at taking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493507/how-do-i-get-the-entityframework-to-check-for-2-parameters) a bit further.

I am attempting to link a couple of objects. First, I would like to associate a `Vertical` with a `Product`. The vertical id will (eventually) be passed in through a constructor, or accessible through a linked object, but for right now I have attempted to manually set the VerticalID.l The code for all three objects is below:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID              { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string Model        { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber   { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID      { get; set; }
    public string Description  { get; set; }

    public int VerticalID = 1;
    public virtual Vertical Vertical { get; set; }

    public virtual ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductPrice Price { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDocument> Documents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetail> Details { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }
}

public class Vertical
{
    public int ID      { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductPrice
{
    public int     ID         { get; set; }
    public int     ProductID  { get; set; }
    public int     VerticalID { get; set; }
    public decimal Value      { get; set; }

    public virtual Product  Product  { get; set; }
    public virtual Vertical Vertical { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

Once I have successfully linked a vertical. I would then like to link a `Product` to a `ProductPrice` using the ProductID and VerticalID foreign keys. Basically, the relationship is:

**1 price per product per vertical.**

I have tried linking a product and a vertical using the fluent api **as recommended in one of the answers of my previous question (linked above)**, but have come up empty handed. Here was my attempt:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductCategory> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductDetail> ProductDetails { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductDocument> Documents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductImage> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProductPrice> Prices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Vertical> Verticals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasRequired(a => a.Vertical)
            .WithRequiredDependent();
    }
}
```

#### How do I link a Product to a vertical using an attribute not mapped to a db column and (more importantly) how do I link a Product to a ProductPrice using 2 foreign keys?

Comment: Why "not mapped"? Further, can you expand on what the multiplicities of the associations `Product`-`ProductPrice`-`Vertical` should be?

Comment: @GertArnold That relationship is a Product (one) => ProductPrice (many). If I was going to write a query it would look like `SELECT * FROM ProductPrices WHERE ProductID = Product.ID AND VerticalID = Product.Vertical.ID LIMIT 1` - does that make sense?

Comment: @GertArnold to answer the "not mapped" question - because the vertical ID could be passed in through a query string, or will probably come from another property (e.g. User.Vertical.ID - or something). That's why VerticalID is hard coded right now.