# ToList() throws an exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I try to retrieve a list from the data base.
However when I call the ToList() method it throws and exception.Knowing that the database is not empty.

```
 var listeRef = from r in db.refAnomalies
                       select r;
        rapportAnomalie rp = new rapportAnomalie();
        List<refAnomalie> listeRefference = listeRef.ToList();
```

The exception : `{"Invalid column name 'rapportAnomalie_code_rapport'."}`

this is my database tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[refAnomalie] (
[code_anomalie]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[libelle_anomalie] NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[score_anomalie]   INT            NOT NULL,
[classe_anomalie]  NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.refAnomalie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([code_anomalie] ASC)
);


 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rapportAnomalie] (
[code_rapport] INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[date_rapport] DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[etat]         NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[code_agence]  INT           NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.rapportAnomalie] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([code_rapport]    ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.rapportAnomalie_dbo.agence_code_agence] FOREIGN KEY    ([code_agence]) REFERENCES [dbo].[agence] ([code_agence]) ON DELETE CASCADE
  );


 GO
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_code_agence]
  ON [dbo].[rapportAnomalie]([code_agence] ASC);
```

rapportAnomalie Class :

```
  [Table("rapportAnomalie")]
   public partial class rapportAnomalie
    {
    [Key]
    public int code_rapport { get; set; }

    public DateTime date_rapport { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string etat { get; set; }

    public int code_agence { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("code_agence")]
    public agence agence { get; set; }

    public List<refAnomalie> listeRefAnomalie { get; set; }
    public List<ligneRapportAnomalie> listeLigneRapportAnomalie { get; set;       }
}
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Where are you defining 'rapportAnomalie_code_rapport?

Comment: I didn't define it. even rapportAnomalie and the Context file doesn't have it

Comment: Are you using Linq2SQL or EF? Your linq query queries a table `refAnomalies`, but you posted the definition and class for a different table (`rapportAnomalie`). Please post the `refAnomalie` table as well.

Comment: There you go. And I'm using EF

Comment: It seems you're using code first.. Can you show us the Mapping class for the same? It looks interesting issue.

Comment: what Mapping class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced

```
var listeRef = from r in db.refAnomalies
                   select r;
```

with

```
String sql = @"select * from refAnomalie";
        List<refAnomalie> listeRefference = new List<refAnomalie>();
        var con =  new SqlConnection("data source=(LocalDb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=Banque;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework");
        using (var command= new SqlCommand(sql,con)){

            con.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                    listeRefference.Add(new refAnomalie
                    {
                        code_anomalie = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        libelle_anomalie = reader.GetString(1),
                        score_anomalie = reader.GetInt32(2),
                        classe_anomalie = reader.GetString(3)
                    });
                    }

        }
```

and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

The error message is quite clear: EF evidently generates a query simliar to...

```
select ..., rapportAnomalie_code_rapport, ...
from refAnomalie
```

...and the error tells you that there is no `rapportAnomalie_code_rapport` column in `refAnomalie`.

You need to take a look at the class that EF generates for `refAnomalie`. There is probably a reference to that mysterious column somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

@Omar, Changing the complete approach is not the solution of the problem. The way I see this problem is you're having naming convention issue with Navigation properties. Which sometime confuses the EF and results in generating a "Guessed" column name which doesn't exist.

I would recommend to thoroughly go through this [Discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11079863/entity-framework-navigation-property-generation-rules/11081568#11081568) about navigation property and name generations. Also check how to overcome this using [InverseProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454938/invalid-column-name-error-when-trying-to-associate-objects-with-entityframework) attribute.

Since We don't have complete details of your EF code first entities it's really hard to point out the problem area. But hope above suggestions will help you re-visit your code and identify the problem.